# Comparing object data to multiple example values from pact matcher typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, pact

I am using pact V3 in typescript to verify a contract with an API. The response example matcher is the following:

```
const userExample = {
  email: string("foo.bar@example.com"),
  id: number(123)
}
```

The actual `response.data` from the API looks like:

```
{
  "email": "foo.bar@example.com",
  "id": 123
}
```

When I execute the test:

```
expect(response.data).toStrictEqual(userExample)
```

I get that it is comparing the `response.data` to the Matcher object instead of the actual example values:

```
contract:test:     - Expected  - 8
contract:test:     + Received  + 2
contract:test: 
contract:test:       Object {
contract:test:     -   "email": Object {
contract:test:     -     "pact:matcher:type": "type",
contract:test:     -     "value": "foo.bar@example.com",
contract:test:     -   },
contract:test:     -   "id": Object {
contract:test:     -     "pact:matcher:type": "number",
contract:test:     -     "value": 123,
contract:test:     -   },
contract:test:     +   "email": "foo.bar@example.com",
contract:test:     +   "id": 123,
contract:test:       }
```

I can get around this by instead doing:

```
expect(response.data.email).toStrictEqual(userExample.email.value)
expect(response.data.id).toStrictEqual(userExample.id.value)
```

But I am trying to figure out if there is a way to compare the entire response without having to specify the `.value` in a separate `expect` function line for each potential value of the `userExample` response?

Full test code below:

```
import { MatchersV3, PactV3 } from "@pact-foundation/pact"

const { like, atLeastOneLike, string, number } = MatchersV3
const provider = new PactV3({
  consumer: "consumer-service",
  provider: "provider-service"
})

const userExample = {
  email: string("foo.bar@example.com"),
  id: number(123),
}

test("get users", async () => {
  provider.addInteraction({
    states: [{ description: "user exists" }],
    uponReceiving: "get users",
    withRequest: {
      method: "GET",
      path: "/users",
    },
    willRespondWith: {
      status: 200,
      body: like({
        users: atLeastOneLike(userExample),
      }),
    },
  })

  await provider.executeTest(async (mockserver) => {
    const userServiceClient = new UserServiceClient(mockserver.url)
    const response = await userServiceClient.getUsers()

    expect(response.data.email).toStrictEqual(userExample.email.value)
    expect(response.data.id).toStrictEqual(userExample.id.value)
  })
})
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of adapter between the Pact matchers and Jest? [`.toStrictEqual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tostrictequalvalue) is a default expectation that knows _nothing_ about Pact.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited to add more of the test code for context, I was following along with the pact foundation js workshop.

Comment: I don't see what you've posted here in e.g. https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-js, all their assertions are against vanilla objects not Pact matchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`reify`](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/master/src/v3/matchers.ts#L498) function to do this (previously called `extractPayload`), to remove the matches from the object.

This being said:

```
const userExample = {
  email: string("foo.bar@example.com"),
  id: number(123),
}
```

is equivalent to

```
const userExample = like({
  email: "foo.bar@example.com",
  id: 123,
})
```

That is, a `like` matcher just matches on types.

`atLeastOneLike` is also an extension of this matcher, but for arrays of objects.

So you could rewrite your test as follows:

```
const userExample = {
  email: "foo.bar@example.com",
  id: 123,
}

test("get users", async () => {
  provider.addInteraction({
    states: [{ description: "user exists" }],
    uponReceiving: "get users",
    withRequest: {
      method: "GET",
      path: "/users",
    },
    willRespondWith: {
      status: 200,
      body: like({
        users: atLeastOneLike(userExample),
      }),
    },
  })

  await provider.executeTest(async (mockserver) => {
    const userServiceClient = new UserServiceClient(mockserver.url)
    const response = await userServiceClient.getUsers()

    expect(response.data.email).toStrictEqual(userExample.email)
    expect(response.data.id).toStrictEqual(userExample.id)
  })
})
```